# Heroku Deploy - Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, heroku, bundler

I'm trying to deploy my app to its heroku staging site and am getting this error:

No source for ruby-1.9.3-p545 provided with debugger-ruby_core_source gem.

Here is my terminal output:

```
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 402, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (328/328), done.
Writing objects: 100% (335/335), 39.22 KiB, done.
Total 335 (delta 219), reused 1 (delta 0)

-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
   Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
   Old: ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
   New: ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24 revision 45159) [x86_64-linux]
   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
   Installing builder (3.0.4)
   Installing multi_json (1.8.4)
   Installing i18n (0.6.9)
   Installing rake (10.1.1)
   Installing journey (1.0.4)
   Installing erubis (2.7.0)
   Installing rack (1.4.5)
   Installing hike (1.2.3)
   Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
   Installing tilt (1.4.1)
   Installing mime-types (1.25.1)
   Installing arel (3.0.3)
   Installing encryptor (1.3.0)
   Installing coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
   Installing execjs (2.0.2)
   Installing tzinfo (0.3.38)
   Installing thor (0.18.1)
   Installing columnize (0.3.6)
   Installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
   Installing debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
   Using bundler (1.5.2)
   Installing json (1.8.1)
   Installing activesupport (3.2.15)
   Installing sass (3.2.13)
   Installing rack-cache (1.2)
   Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
   Installing rack-ssl (1.3.3)
   Installing debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.1)
   Installing sprockets (2.2.2)
   Installing treetop (1.4.15)
   Installing rest-client (1.6.7)
   Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
   Installing attr_encrypted (1.3.1)
   Installing uglifier (2.4.0)
   Installing rdoc (3.12.2)
   Installing activemodel (3.2.15)
   Using stripe (1.9.9) 
   Installing mail (2.5.4)
   Installing actionpack (3.2.15)
   Installing activerecord (3.2.15)
   Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
   /tmp/build_c3dc4410-aa3d-49f3-898a-cdf549b66956/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby extconf.rb
   checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
   checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
   checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
   checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
   Makefile creation failed
   **************************************************************************
   No source for ruby-1.9.3-p545 provided with debugger-ruby_core_source gem.
   **************************************************************************
   *** extconf.rb failed ***
   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
   details.  You may need configuration options.
   Provided configuration options:
   --with-opt-dir
   --without-opt-dir
   --with-opt-include
   --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
   --with-opt-lib
   --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
   --with-make-prog
   --without-make-prog
   --srcdir=.
   --curdir
   --ruby=/tmp/build_c3dc4410-aa3d-49f3-898a-cdf549b66956/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby
   --with-ruby-dir
   --without-ruby-dir
   --with-ruby-include
   --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
   --with-ruby-lib
   --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
   Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_c3dc4410-aa3d-49f3-898a-cdf549b66956/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/debugger-1.6.5 for inspection.
   Results logged to /tmp/build_c3dc4410-aa3d-49f3-898a-cdf549b66956/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/debugger-1.6.5/ext/ruby_debug/gem_make.out
   Installing activeresource (3.2.15)
   Installing actionmailer (3.2.15)
   Installing pg (0.17.1)
   An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.5), and Bundler cannot
   continue.
   Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.6.5'` succeeds before bundling.
   Installing builder (3.0.4)
   Installing multi_json (1.8.4)
   Installing i18n (0.6.9)
   Installing rake (10.1.1)
   Installing journey (1.0.4)
   Installing erubis (2.7.0)
   Installing rack (1.4.5)
   Installing hike (1.2.3)
   Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
   Installing tilt (1.4.1)
   Installing mime-types (1.25.1)
   Installing arel (3.0.3)
   Installing encryptor (1.3.0)
   Installing coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
   Installing execjs (2.0.2)
   Installing tzinfo (0.3.38)
   Installing thor (0.18.1)
   Installing columnize (0.3.6)
   Installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
   Installing debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
   Using bundler (1.5.2)
   Installing json (1.8.1)
   Installing activesupport (3.2.15)
   Installing sass (3.2.13)
   Installing rack-cache (1.2)
   Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
   Installing rack-ssl (1.3.3)
   Installing debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.1)
   Installing sprockets (2.2.2)
   Installing treetop (1.4.15)
   Installing rest-client (1.6.7)
   Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
   Installing attr_encrypted (1.3.1)
   Installing uglifier (2.4.0)
   Installing rdoc (3.12.2)
   Installing activemodel (3.2.15)
   Using stripe (1.9.9)
   Installing mail (2.5.4)
   Installing actionpack (3.2.15)
   Installing activerecord (3.2.15)
   
   Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
   
   /tmp/build_c3dc4410-aa3d-49f3-898a-cdf549b66956/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby extconf.rb
   checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
   checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
   checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
   checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
   Makefile creation failed
   **************************************************************************
   No source for ruby-1.9.3-p545 provided with debugger-ruby_core_source gem.
   **************************************************************************
   *** extconf.rb failed ***
   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
   details.  You may need configuration options.
   
   Provided configuration options:
   --with-opt-dir
   --without-opt-dir
   --with-opt-include
   --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
   --with-opt-lib
   --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
   --with-make-prog
   --without-make-prog
   --srcdir=.
   --curdir
   --ruby=/tmp/build_c3dc4410-aa3d-49f3-898a-cdf549b66956/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby
   --with-ruby-dir
   --without-ruby-dir
   --with-ruby-include
   --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
   --with-ruby-lib
   --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
   
   
   Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_c3dc4410-aa3d-49f3-898a-cdf549b66956/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/debugger-1.6.5 for inspection.
   Results logged to /tmp/build_c3dc4410-aa3d-49f3-898a-cdf549b66956/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/debugger-1.6.5/ext/ruby_debug/gem_make.out
   Installing activeresource (3.2.15)
   Installing actionmailer (3.2.15)
   Installing pg (0.17.1)
   An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.5), and Bundler cannot
   continue.
   Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.6.5'` succeeds before bundling.

   Failed to install gems via Bundler.

   Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

   [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

I have already tried to run:

```
 "bundle update debugger-ruby_core_source" and "bundle update debugger"
```

and have tried:

```
 "gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.1.2' -- --with-ruby-include=\$rvm_path/src/ruby-1.9.3-p545"
```

here is my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails', '3.2.15'


# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'

gem 'attr_encrypted'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'jasmine-rails'
  gem 'rack_session_access'
  gem 'launchy'
end

gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

#this for payment processing
gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby'

# To use debugger
gem 'debugger'
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

## update:

I went ahead and removed debugger entirely from my gemfile, bundled, and committed and that solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the debugger gem to development.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#debugger-gems-fail-to-install